# My program can not run help me

Tags: jsp

**Hello** I have a problem with jsp program
I don't know what happen I can't slove this problem

1. my program can run

but when i write "searchmode.jsp"  my program can't run

```
"<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>"
```

line 1 has redline under code
and then other file in my project can't run too

help me to solve this problem please

thank for answer

Answer (score 0):

this is likely trivial but why do you have quotations in the beginning? And not like this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```